# How to set default kernel or specify it when execute in a shell

Tags: kernel, default, jupyter-notebook

I want to execute and convert notebook. I have 2 kernels - python2 and python3. But when i execute this shell command, it uses python2 when i want python3 kernel.

`jupyter nbconvert --to html --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --execute myfile.ipynb`

How to change default kernel or specify it in a command ?

Answer (score 1):

--ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=

Name of kernel can be looked here:
jupyter kernelspec list